# dynamic associative array?

Tags: php

I have array returned

```
$header_html = array(1=>array('width'=>40,
                               'sort_case'=>23,
                               'title'=>'AxA'),
                      2=>array('width'=>50,
                               'sort_case'=>7,
                               'title'=>'B2B'),
                      3=>array('width'=>100,
                               'sort_case'=>12,
                               'title'=>'C12')
                      );
```

I want to get new array that  depend on $header_array=array('AxA','B2B','C12')

for examples:

```
 if have $header_array=array('C12','B2B','AxA').
```

the new $header_html will be:

```
$header_html = array(
                      1=>array('width'=>100,
                               'sort_case'=>12,
                               'title'=>'C12'),                         
                      2=>array('width'=>50,
                               'sort_case'=>7,
                               'title'=>'B2B'),
                      3=>array('width'=>40,
                               'sort_case'=>23,
                               'title'=>'AxA')

                      );
```

and so on...

Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: So, you want to sort the array in descending alphabetical order by `['title']`?

Comment: @adam, From his example, yes. But I think the OP may want a functionality where you can supply the arguments of how to re-order the array and that I do not think exists in a single function.

Comment: Just update the question..
it is not the matter of sorting .the new array will depend on 
$header_array=array('C12','B2B','AxA') or
$header_array=array('B2B','C112','AxA') and so on..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the array with a custom comparison function using [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
  // Sort via $a['title'] and $b['title']
}

usort($header_html, 'cmp');
```

The trick is coming up with a comparison function that does what you want. To simply sort backwards by title, you could use:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
  if ($a['title'] == $b['title'])
    return 0;

  // usually return -1 if $a < $b, but we're sorting backwards 
  return ($a['title'] < $b['title'] ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Comment: usort() takes a refernce and return a boolean value

Answer (score 2):

In PHP 5.3, you can easily do this with a functor and usort.

```
class MyComparator {
  protected $order = array();

  public function __construct() {
    $values = func_get_args();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($values as $v) {
      $this->order[$v] = $i;
      $i++;
    }
  }

  public function __invoke($a, $b) {
    $vala = isset($this->order[$a['title']]) ?
      $this->order[$a['title']] : count($this->order);
    $valb = isset($this->order[$b['title']]) ?
      $this->order[$b['title']] : count($this->order);
    if($vala == $valb) return 0;
    return $vala < $valb ? -1 : 1;
  }
}
```

You can use it like that:

```
$sorter = new MyComparator('CCC', 'AAA', 'BBB');
usort($header_html, $sorter);
```

Comment: Clever use of `__invoke()` but it should be emphasized that this does not work in PHP pior to 5.3.

Answer (score 2):

You need a user-defined sort so you can access individual fields of the elements to sort:

```
function mysort($a, $b)
{
  global $header_array;
  $pos1 = array_search($a["title"], $header_array);
  $pos2 = array_search($b["title"], $header_array);
  if ($pos1 == $pos2) { return 0; }
  return $pos1 < $pos2 ? -1 : 1;
}

$header_array = array("CCC", "BBB", "AAA");
usort($header_html, "mysort");

print_r($header_array);
```

**note:** [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort) returns true on success or false on failure; it does not return the resorted array.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a function to return the array elements in the order you specify in `$header_array`.  If so, here's a stab:

```
function header_resort($header_array, $header_html) {
    foreach($header_array as $i => $val) {
        foreach($header_html as $obj) {
            if( $obj->title == $val )
                $header_html_new[$i] = $obj;
        }
    }
    return $header_html_new;
}
```